# Else block being executed when if statement is true

Tags: python

I'm new to Python (learning in school) and having trouble understanding this simple code:

```
# Take a planet name as input. Example: Mars, Neptune, Mercury etc.
myPlanet = raw_input("Enter the name of a planet: ")

# Check if 'myPlanet' is stored in the list of dictionaries.
for dictionary in planets:
    if (dictionary["name"] == myPlanet):
        print(dictionary)
    else:
        print("Unknown planet specified.")
        return
```

Example output:

```
Enter the name of a planet: Mercury
{'radius': 2439.7, 'name': 'Mercury'}
Unknown planet specified.
```

Why is the `else` block executed here, when Mercury exists in the list?

And the output 'Unknown planet specified'? is shown. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: add `break` if match is found.

Comment: They still teach Python 2 in school? Python 2 has reached end of life and is no longer supported. End of life was planned for 2015 but [in 2014 they stretched it to 2020](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/#update-april-2014). Now Python 2 is really dead. Please make your teacher aware of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you check if a match is found or not ***for every dictionary***. Assuming there are a few planets and you find a match, you keep iterating to the next planet and when it doesn't match you will get to the `else` statement. You might want to unindent the `else` and add a `break` to the `if` to create a [`for/else`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) construct:

```py
for dictionary in planets:
    if (dictionary["name"] == myPlanet):
        print(dictionary)
        break
else:
    print("Unknown planet specified.")
```

Here, the `else` will only be executed in case the loop exhausted ***without breaking***, which means that none of the planets matched the condition.